# In an Inkscape extension, how do I set a path's control points?

Tags: python, inkscape

I am trying to build an Inkscape extension for learning purposes, and would like to manipulate a path's control points.

I know I can list them like this:

```
inkex.utils.debug([ p for p in self.svg.selected[0].path.control_points ])
```

but I cannot set them - `path.control_points` is a generator.

Is there a way besides converting this to an SVG "d" attribute, manipulating it with svgpathtools and setting it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a way to do that if you know what is inside the path. If it is random path or any path, the code will be complicated.

```
pel = self.svg.selected[0] # assuming selected is a path
path_old = pel.path
```

Assuming your path has those 2 components, or similar a few known components.

```
[Move(80.3412, 87.9089), Curve(99.575, 67.2665, 
        103.398, 73.9063, 113.129, 83.6942)]
```

You can recreate a new path with same components.

```
path_new = Path()

old_move = path_old[0]
new_move = Move(old_move.x + 10, old_move.y + 11) # modify Move coordinates
old_curve = path_old[1]
new_curve = Curve(......)

path_new.append(new_move)
path_new.append(new_curve)
```

Depending on your needs, sometimes maybe it is easier to manipulate the `d` attribute directly.